# Why cant i delete a local Git branch in IntelliJ?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

So Im new to Git, and to test i have created the local Branch "test". But for some reason, I can not delete it, just the master branch. I just dont have the option to do that, but there is not a single person on the internet that asked the same question,
[image: see here]

Answer (score 6):

Try switching to another branch (e.g. master or main) via checkout. Then your branch will be deletable.

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliJ IDEA documentation mentions, regarding [local branch deletion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-branches.html#delete-branch):

> After you have integrated the changes from a feature branch into the main line of development, you can delete the branch you do not need anymore.

Still, assuming test is not currently checked out, you should still be able to, in the `Branches` popup or from the `Branches` pane of the Git tool window, select the branch you want to delete and choose `Delete`.

The documentation adds:

> If the branch contained commits that have not yet been merged to its upstream branch or to the current branch, it will still be deleted immediately (equivalent to the `git branch --D` or `git branch --delete --force` command), but the notification will also contain a link allowing you to view the unmerged commits.

If that fails, you can still fall back to the command line to delete said branch, again, assuming it is not currently checked out.